# SDD extracted from old laptop does not work independently

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive

I dismantled an old Win 7 laptop containing two 128GB Toshiba [THNSNC128GMMJ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/b00ti3va4u) SSDs using [this](https://www.how-fixit.com/laptop-repair-guides/sony-vaio/sony-vaio-pcg-31111/) tutorial. At 7:15, you can see how the SDDs are extracted (they both sit in some type of frame that holds them together). I tried to connect them via USB to my new machine using [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075TBNC56) cable. One SSD is not recognized when plugged in, the other is recognized, but Win 10 pops up a message saying the file system is not recognized and the drive has to be formatted.
I've done something similar in the past (between Win 7 machines) and it worked, so I was expecting to see the drive in the explorer with all files being accessible. Could it be that these drives were running in some kind of RAID configuration in my old machine (I think originally it used to show just one drive with 256 GB capacity). If so, how would I access the data. If not, what else could be the issue?

Edit: I checked in Disk Management where both disks show up, "Disk 1" and "Disk 2" (see below image). The sizes shown there are incorrect and correspond to the partition sizes on my old machine. Furthermore, I noticed, that when I plug in "Disk 2" (while "Disk 1" is not plugged in) two new drive letters are generated under This PC. So, it seems like I need to recreate the RAID 0 setup that I had on my old machine in order to access my files. But how would I do this?

[image]

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities, and yes, RAID is a likely one. You are generally better off connecting drives directly to a PC with a data interface as this removes USB abstraction (which has been known to cause issues). At minimum this would tell you if the second drive is recognisable in the BIOS... But that's only the first step.

Comment: @davidgo, appologies for my ignorance. could you elaborate on what you mean by "connect via data interface". What would that look like?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. Connect the drives to the SATA interface on the motherboard of a PC (rather then going through a USB interface)

Comment: @davigo. Thanks, I am unable to connect directly to montherboard, but I do get both drives to show up in Disk Management (see my edit to the original question).